# How do I (automatically) update my software that is running on a Server from an online repository?

Tags: git, server, gitlab, online-repository

I am developing some software that will be running on a raspberry-pi. I do not want to manually hook up (SSH, ...) to the device every time to update the software. Currently I am using GitLab to store the code. I was thinking about the possibility to automatically update the software on the server as soon as I push an update to the master-branch. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Look at https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

Comment: Something I did find: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1193583/install-github-software-as-a-repo

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of the [continuous deployment feature](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/introduction/#continuous-deployment) where the deploy job is [specified with only changes to master](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlyexcept-basic) in the yml file. Similar to:

```
deploy:
  script:
    - some script
  only:
    - master
```

In most cases, you can also [make use of SSH within the CI/CD pipeline](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ssh_keys/README.html).